# How to pass value to ASP.NET Core partial view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I need to use the one partial view many times in the same view.

My problem is that I need to change the `id` of a specific element in the partial view. So, what I need is to pass a value throughout the partial view tag helper every time I call it.

For example:

#### The partial view

Let's call it `_list`

```
<ul id="@val">
   <li> bla bla bla </li>
   <li> bla bla bla </li>
   <li> bla bla bla </li>
   <li> bla bla bla </li>
</ul>
```

I need to call the partial view `_list` with the possibility to pass the id value.

#### Passing data to the partial view

```
<partial attripute-to-pass-value="id1" name="_list" />
<partial attripute-to-pass-value="id2" name="_list" />
<partial attripute-to-pass-value="id3" name="_list" />
<partial attripute-to-pass-value="id4" name="_list" />
```

I don't know which attribute can be used to do this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Did you check the [model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/partial-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1#model) attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `model` tag to pass your value.

Like this:

**Controller**

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>
    {
        1,2,3,4
    };
    return View(list);
}
```

**Index cshtml**

```
@model List<int>

@foreach (int id in Model)
{
    <partial name="_ProductPartial" model="id" />
}
```

**Partial cshtml**

```
@model int

<h1>My Id = @Model</h1>
```